# C++ Vector Question, if (vector[i] % 2 == 0) { total_even = total_even + vector[i];

Tags: c++, vector

I'm learning C++ in codeacademy and there is an assignment where the code has to output of "Sum of even numbers is 12" and "Product of odd numbers is 27". Part of the code I'm trying to get an understanding of.

I'm trying to understand why the mod %2 == 0? By making it **== 0** , does that make it have a true value? Or why can't it be written **(vector [i] %2)**
If possible can someone explain this code.

FULL CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
int main() {
 
  int total_even = 0;
  int product_odd = 1;
 
  std::vector<int> vector = {2, 4, 3, 6, 1, 9};
 
  for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
 
    if (vector[i] % 2 == 0) {
 
      total_even = total_even + vector[i];
 
    } else {
 
      product_odd = product_odd * vector[i];
 
    }
 
  }
 
  std::cout << "Sum of even: " << total_even << "\n";
  std::cout << "Product of odd: " << product_odd;
 
}
```

T**he part of the code I'm trying to undderstand**

```
 if (vector[i] % 2 == 0) {
 
      total_even = total_even + vector[i];
```

Comment: If "n mod 2" is zero, then the number is even.  Are you clear on that?  As always in C, there are lots of ways to write that.  `vector[i] % 2 == 0` or `!(vector[i] % 2)` or `vector[i] & 1 == 0` or `!(vector[i] & 1)`.

Comment: 0 (zero) is considered False value hence you need to either do == 0 or do !(vector[i] % 2)

Comment: `vector[i] % 2 == 0` can be read as "the value of `vector[i]` is even".

Comment: in c++ `=` is assignment operator and `==` is for equality condition check

Answer (score 0):

In plain english, that line says, "If the value at the i'th index of vector mod 2 equals 0 then ...". The mod 2 equals zero part tells you if the number is odd or even. If it's 0, then the value is evenly divisible by 2 and therefore, even. Otherwise, the value is odd.

Answer (score 0):

First, if a modulo 2 of a number is greater than zero it is odd, i.e. `5 mod 2 = 1`, whereas `4 mod 2 = 0`.

Second, you can not simply write `vector[i] %2` as a zero value will be evaluated to `false`. Any other value `> 0` will be evaluated to `true`.

Consider this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << static_cast<bool>(0) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << static_cast<bool>(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << static_cast<bool>(5%2) << "\n"; // 5%2 = 1
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << static_cast<bool>(4%2) << "\n"; // 4%2 = 0    

    return 0;
}
```

This yields:

```
false
true
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Mod(%) operator returns the remainder of two numbers resulted from their division.

Eg. 4%2 is 0 (when 4 is divided by 2, the remainder will be 0)

Now, let's consider this line by line:

`if (vector[i] % 2 == 0)`

Here, for every iteration in vector's traversal, we are looking if the number at current index i will return 0 as the remainder when it's divided by 2(condition for even number).

`total_even = total_even + vector[i];`

Here, if the aforementioned condition satisfies, we are just doing an overall sum of all numbers that satisfies your condition, i.e., it's an even number.

Hope this helps! Happy coding :)